# Dependency Injection order in AngularJS

Tags: dependency-injection, angularjs

In AngularJS, does the order of my dependencies matter?.

Example:

Suppose I have an `'awesomeGlobalService'` to handle a set of services common to all the modules of my app.

Should I inject it first?:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['awesomeGlobalService', 'secondModule', 'anotherModule', ...])
```

or should I inject it last?:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['secondModule', 'anotherModule', ... 'awesomeGlobalService'])
```

or it really doesn't matter as long is in the injection array?

Comment: Are you asking if it matters in terms of program behavior, or code style? Or both?

Comment: Program behavior, I want to avoid an error of type "service not defined" because the definition is not yet injected

Comment: It does not matter, which order you specify in the dependency list. But if there is a service with the same name in multiple dependent modules, then last one overrides every other occurances.

Comment: @PSL could you please put your comment as answer to mark it as good. Thank you for the help

Comment: Related: [Order of AngularJS dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096020/order-of-angularjs-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below picture depicts the flow of life cycle when injecting dependencies:

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10676729)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !!! How to insert the image here ? your answer would be appreciated